# Using regex to split (limited experience w/ regex)

Tags: java, regex, string, split, substring

I have limited experience and knowledge of regex. What I need to do is split a string into multiple substrings.

The string in question is

```
String str =
   "Brayden Schenn, C GAMES PLAYED: 13, GOALS: 3, ASSISTS: 6," +
   " POINTS: 9, PLUS/MINUS: 5, PIM: 7";
```

I want to split this up into substrings, other strings, ie.

```
String gamesPlayed = "13";
String goals = "3";
etc
```

or something like that so I can pull out how many goals, assists, etc. are in the parent string.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Regex is really easy to learn and insanely useful. there are heaps of articles on the net so i suggest you just have a google for one and pick it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following regular expression `(([\w/]+):\s?(\d+)),?` to match all the `key:value` in your String, and then just extract `GOALS` with `group(2)` and `3` with `group(3)`.

The regular expression reads like this:

```
(            # capture key/value (without the comma)
  (          # capture key (in group 2)
    [\w/]+   # any word character including / one or more times
  )
  :          # followed by a colon
  \s?        # followed by a space (or not)
  (          # capture value (in group 3)
    \d+      # one or mor digit
   )
)
,?           # followed by a comma (or not)
```

It should match the following considering your String:

```
PLAYED: 13
GOALS: 3
ASSISTS: 6
POINTS: 9
PLUS/MINUS: 5
PIM: 7
```

Here's the Java code:

```
String s = "Brayden Schenn, C GAMES PLAYED: 13, GOALS: 3, ASSISTS: 6, POINTS: 9, PLUS/MINUS: 5, PIM: 7";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(([\\w/]+):\\s?(\\d+)),?").matcher(s);
Map<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
// find them all
while (m.find()) {
   values.put(m.group(2), Integer.valueOf(m.group(3)));
}
// print the values
System.out.println("Games Played: " + values.get("PLAYED"));
System.out.println("Goals: " + values.get("GOALS"));
System.out.println("Assists: " + values.get("ASSISTS"));
System.out.println("Points: " + values.get("POINTS"));
System.out.println("Plus/Minus: " + values.get("PLUS/MINUS"));
System.out.println("Pim: " + values.get("PIM"));
```

Answer (score 3):

What I would :

- First split using `,`
- Then split using `:`

I've got close to zero experience in Java but that's what I'd suggest :

```
String initialStr =
   "GAMES PLAYED: 13, GOALS: 3, ASSISTS: 6, POINTS: 9,"+
   " PLUS/MINUS: 5, PIM: 7";
String colon = ": ";
Map< String, Integer> keyValuePairs = new HashMap<>();// Java 7 diamond    
String[] parts = initialStr.split(",");
for( String keyValue : parts ) {
   String[] pair = keyValue.split(colon);
   keyValuePairs.put( pair[0], Integer.parseInt( pair[1] ));
}
```

Ask keyValuePairs as follow :

```
assert keyValuePairs.get( "GAMES PLAYED" ) == 13;
```

Comment: @nneonneo I just hope there is no syntax error in the above (Java is *really* not my thing...) :-)

Comment: I'd give you another +1 for stepping outside your comfort zone if I could ;)

Comment: Please add a for loop around parts and put the result in a Map< String, String >

Comment: @Aubin That's exactly what I had in mind, but I won't attempt it - coz in the end I'll definitely mess things up. If you're more experienced in Java than me, then please go ahead and add it as a complete answer (this way it'd be much more helpful fot the OP).

Comment: OP initial String starts with `Brayden Schenn, C GAMES PLAYED: 13` not `GAMES PLAYED`.

Comment: @nneonneo: When you pass string into `split`, it is treated as regex. Fun thing is going to happen if one is not aware of that and pass `"."` in...